# Finding an Employee without using so many Conditional Statements using Structs

Tags: c#

I have written this code for my school project program (it's still incomplete) but it does the job for the most part. The thing is, we have to use structs to make a program of pre-defined employees and then we have to make it so that we can use any attribute (Name, Employee ID, Blood group, Age etc.) to search through all of the employees.

I have found a way using conditional statements (which as of right now, works for name and employee ID). I have realized that the code is too long and there might be another way to search through the program. I also want to make it show all male/female employees when we use Gender as the searching attribute.

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace Terminals
    {
        class Program
    
    
        {
            struct Employee
            {
                public string Name;
                public int EmployeeID;
                public string BloodGroup;
                public int Salary;
                public int Age;
                public string Gender;
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Employee employee1;
                Employee employee2;
                Employee employee3;
                Employee employee4;
                Employee employee5;
                Employee employee6;
    
                employee1.Name = "James";
                employee1.EmployeeID = int.Parse("10");
                employee1.BloodGroup = "B +ive";
                employee1.Salary = int.Parse("500000");
                employee1.Age = int.Parse("26");
                employee1.Gender = "Male";
    
                employee2.Name = "Ali Khan";
                employee2.EmployeeID = int.Parse("20");
                employee2.BloodGroup = "O +ive";
                employee2.Salary = int.Parse("250000");
                employee2.Age = int.Parse("22");
                employee2.Gender = "Male";
    
                employee3.Name = "Jessica Hills";
                employee3.EmployeeID = int.Parse("30");
                employee3.BloodGroup = "A -ive";
                employee3.Salary = int.Parse("400000");
                employee3.Age = int.Parse("25");
                employee3.Gender = "Female";
    
                employee4.Name = "William";
                employee4.EmployeeID = int.Parse("40");
                employee4.BloodGroup = "O -ive";
                employee4.Salary = int.Parse("700000");
                employee4.Age = int.Parse("29");
                employee4.Gender = "Male";
    
                employee5.Name = "Lizzy";
                employee5.EmployeeID = int.Parse("50");
                employee5.BloodGroup = "AB +ive";
                employee5.Salary = int.Parse("70000");
                employee5.Age = int.Parse("19");
                employee5.Gender = "Female";
    
                employee6.Name = "Kyle";
                employee6.EmployeeID = int.Parse("60");
                employee6.BloodGroup = "AB -ive";
                employee6.Salary = int.Parse("600000");
                employee6.Age = int.Parse("21");
                employee6.Gender = "Male";
    
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of the term you would like to search with (1-6)?");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Name");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Employee ID");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Blood Group");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Salary");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Age");
                Console.WriteLine("6. Gender");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number (1-6): ");
                int searchterm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (searchterm == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the employee: ");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (name == employee1.Name)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee1.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee1.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee1.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee1.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee1.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee1.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (name == employee2.Name)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee2.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee2.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee2.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee2.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee2.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee2.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (name == employee3.Name)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee3.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee3.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee3.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee3.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee3.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee3.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (name == employee4.Name)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee4.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee4.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee4.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee4.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee4.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee4.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (name == employee5.Name)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee5.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee5.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee5.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee5.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee5.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee5.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (name == employee6.Name)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee1.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee6.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee6.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee6.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee6.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee6.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
                        return;
    
                    }
                }
    
                if (searchterm == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee ID of the employee");
                    int employeeid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (employeeid == employee1.EmployeeID)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee1.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee1.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee1.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee1.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee1.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee1.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (employeeid == employee2.EmployeeID)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee2.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee2.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee2.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee2.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee2.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee2.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (employeeid == employee3.EmployeeID)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee3.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee3.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee3.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee3.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee3.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee3.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (employeeid == employee4.EmployeeID)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee4.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee4.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee4.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee4.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee4.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee4.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (employeeid == employee5.EmployeeID)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee5.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee5.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee5.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee5.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee5.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee5.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else if (employeeid == employee6.EmployeeID)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name: " + employee6.Name +"   ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee6.EmployeeID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee6.BloodGroup);
                        Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee6.Salary);
                        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee6.Age);
                        Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee6.Gender);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        return;
                        
                    }
    
    
    
    
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you waiting to tell us that you aren't allowed to use loops?

Comment: I can use them, I just have to use Structures and that is what I did, I don't have any other restrictionsI am still a beginner so yeah..

Comment: You may want to look at [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

Comment: Organize all the employers into a *collection*, say, *array* `Employee[]` or *list*, `List<Employee>` then loop over the collection

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)**

Comment: I think @DmitryBychenko's suggestion is spot-on, and will help you reduce all of that repeated if-check code, with a bit of rework to loop through a collection. That said: this really is off-topic here. Might want to consider the codereview stack exchange, if looking for implementation feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, LINQ will be your friend here, and using a collection, like a `List<Employee>` also helps tremendously. You can eliminate the `else if` logic and shorten the code up by a good amount.

For the `Employee emp = employeeList.Find(employee => employee.Name == name);` line, you would need to change the predicate to `Find` by the correct struct member depending on the user input.  If it can't find the `Employee` out of the list, the `else` logic will report so (this too would also need to be specific to each search condition). I also added a private method to seed the list of employees.  A simple method to contain all the console output lines will also shorten this up even more - simply supply the found `Employee` to it.

The only issue with this is if two or more employees have the same value for one of their members.  It looks like none of your seeded employees share anything in common except `Gender`, in which case you would need to filter on an additional attribute to narrow it down to one employee, or output all the found employees by the search criteria. `.Find` will return the first Employee that matches the criteria, so that won't work (or at least, it would only output the first found Employee!) You could change this code to use `.FindAll` instead, and then pass a new `List<Employee>` to the private methods, and loop over all the employees in the list, outputting each of their information. Overloading the `ValidateEmployee` method I wrote to take in a `List<Employee>` should do the trick.  You could make all your conditions perform a `.FindAll` and delete the `ValidateEmployee` method that takes in a single `Employee`, up to you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Terminals
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Employee
        {
            public string Name;
            public int EmployeeID;
            public string BloodGroup;
            public int Salary;
            public int Age;
            public string Gender;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> employeeList = SeedEmployees();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of the term you would like to search with (1-6):");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Name");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Employee ID");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Blood Group");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Salary");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Age");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Gender");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number (1-6): ");
            int searchterm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (searchterm == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the employee: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                Employee emp = employeeList.Find(employee => employee.Name == name);

                ValidateEmployee(emp);
            }
            else if (searchterm == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the gender of the employee: ");
                string gender = Console.ReadLine();
                List<Employee> emps = employeeList.FindAll(employee => employee.Gender == gender);

                ValidateEmployee(emps);
            }

            //the rest of your "if" conditions for search terms...

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done. Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ValidateEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            if (emp.Equals(default(Employee)))
            {
                //employee not found
                Console.WriteLine($"Employee not found by supplied input. Please try again.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //output the emplyee info
                OutputEmployeeInfo(emp);
            }
        }

        private static void ValidateEmployee(List<Employee> emps)
        {
            foreach (Employee emp in emps)
            {
                if (emp.Equals(default(Employee)))
                {
                    //employee not found
                    Console.WriteLine($"Employee not found by supplied input.");
                }
                else
                {
                    //output the emplyee info
                    OutputEmployeeInfo(emp);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OutputEmployeeInfo(Employee employee)
        {
            Console.Write("Name: " + employee.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + employee.EmployeeID);
            Console.WriteLine("Blood Group: " + employee.BloodGroup);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary: " + employee.Salary);
            Console.WriteLine("Age: " + employee.Age);
            Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + employee.Gender);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<Employee> SeedEmployees()
        {
            Employee employee1;
            Employee employee2;
            Employee employee3;
            Employee employee4;
            Employee employee5;
            Employee employee6;

            employee1.Name = "James";
            employee1.EmployeeID = int.Parse("10");
            employee1.BloodGroup = "B +ive";
            employee1.Salary = int.Parse("500000");
            employee1.Age = int.Parse("26");
            employee1.Gender = "Male";

            employee2.Name = "Ali Khan";
            employee2.EmployeeID = int.Parse("20");
            employee2.BloodGroup = "O +ive";
            employee2.Salary = int.Parse("250000");
            employee2.Age = int.Parse("22");
            employee2.Gender = "Male";

            employee3.Name = "Jessica Hills";
            employee3.EmployeeID = int.Parse("30");
            employee3.BloodGroup = "A -ive";
            employee3.Salary = int.Parse("400000");
            employee3.Age = int.Parse("25");
            employee3.Gender = "Female";

            employee4.Name = "William";
            employee4.EmployeeID = int.Parse("40");
            employee4.BloodGroup = "O -ive";
            employee4.Salary = int.Parse("700000");
            employee4.Age = int.Parse("29");
            employee4.Gender = "Male";

            employee5.Name = "Lizzy";
            employee5.EmployeeID = int.Parse("50");
            employee5.BloodGroup = "AB +ive";
            employee5.Salary = int.Parse("70000");
            employee5.Age = int.Parse("19");
            employee5.Gender = "Female";

            employee6.Name = "Kyle";
            employee6.EmployeeID = int.Parse("60");
            employee6.BloodGroup = "AB -ive";
            employee6.Salary = int.Parse("600000");
            employee6.Age = int.Parse("21");
            employee6.Gender = "Male";

            return new List<Employee>
            {
                employee1,
                employee2,
                employee3,
                employee4,
                employee5,
                employee6
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you will change all that int.Parse("10") for author to just numbers? It looks very weird.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev true, there is no need to start with a string value and parse it.  The original post had it that way though, so I left it.

Comment: As an additional improvement, you could also make use of a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) instead of a bunch of if/else ifs, but that's fairly minor.  It would probably shorten this down even more.